# What is the difference between 2 versions of webdriverbackedselenium

Tags: selenium

This is version 1. It is a part of webdriver-selenium project. 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.webdriver/webdriver-selenium/0.9.7376/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverBackedSelenium.java#WebDriverBackedSelenium

This is version 2. It's a part of selenium-java. 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.20.0/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverBackedSelenium.java#WebDriverBackedSelenium

What is the difference between these 2 versions? I'm trying to port over some legacy tests and want to know if it makes a difference whether we use one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd strongly suggest you pull the latest selenium from their site: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list.  Don't even attempt to use 0.9.7 as that is over a year old, hundreds of bugs have been fixed probably in the webdriverbackedselenium realm.  I'd strongly also suggest putting a code freeze on using any selenium 1 features going forward and just use webdriverbackedselenium to get sel 1 tests running in sel 2.  There are many benefits of doing so but this is not the thread for that.

Comment: also to enforce the convert from sel 1 to sel 2.  I'm at the selenium conference and the project lead just announced that selenium 1 is in maintenance mode, meaning no new features and probably a lot of stuff will be deprecated in selenium 3.  Mike davis, from google talked about migrating tests from sel 1 to sel 2, it was a lightning talked and slides aren't up but i'll share the other presentations from the conferences: http://www.slideshare.net/seleniumconf

Comment: thanks that really helped. The thing is the the tests seem to be a little slow when I use the latest version of WebDriverBackedSelenium. So I was just wondering if there's a faster alternative to the webdriver backed selenium version that is backward compatible.

Comment: bite the bullet and convert to selenium 2, i know it sounds like a daunting task but if you've designred your framework well and decoupled stuff it shouldnt be too bad.  also the new API for sel 2 is much more intuitive

Comment: We definitely want to cut over to selenium 2 in the longer run. But on the way to the upgrade, we want to be able run the set of legacy tests that we have. Selenium RC did not have support for locator strategies.So WebDriverBackedSelenium wastes a lot of time finding the element it needs.But there doesnt seem to be any other solution in the interim.

Comment: why not branch your code and start working on migration on that branch.  What do you mean no support for locator strategies?